# FOLD not working on very long lines

Tags: split, line, fold

I have a fold command as below to split a file with very long line into multiple lines. It works if the file is small. But if the length of the file is too long, it stops adding new line character half way.

```
fold -b -w 3000 <<filename>>
```

Is there an alternate way to do this? I am on RHEL.

Comment: `yes | tr -d '\n' | fold -bw 3000` works fine for me even after several gibibytes. Can you give more details as to your exact symptoms

Comment: Is the file strictly ASCII? The `-b` option may interact with UTF-8 locale if the data is arbitrary bytes.